# responsive table with variable column number

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tablelayout

I have to show user really huge link cloud - something about 1000 links. It's natural I use tables for that purpose, but tables are not responsive -- on mobile devices I am getting extremely small links, which on small PR-screens I am getting a scrollbar.

What I want is CSS framework to decide, how many columns could be comfortable shown to user, while link size still stays comfortable. So, its:

```
link    link    link    link    link
link    link    link    link    link
link    link    link    link    link
```

on huge screen or:

```
link    link
link    link
link    link
link    link
link    link
link    link
link    link
```

On mobile. How do I do that using *Bootstrap*?

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap is a 12 column grid system, and you can't divide 12 by 5, so you can have 4 or 6 columns in your huge screen.
If you want 6 columns replace `col-md-3` with `col-md-2`
Anyway, you definitely want to read bootstrap docs:http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">link</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">link</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">link</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">link</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">link</div>
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If vertical ordering of the "columns" is not important then you can simply use floated blocks with fixed width. It should be responsive:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block">Link #1</div>
    <div class="block">Link #2</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/uv4lFbu8gQXG2otO4wlN?p=preview

Comment: If you set some fixed width for link container -- it might work. But vertical alignment would be nice.

Comment: Vertical allignement is also possible with CSS columns.